# Strange behavior of System.WeakReference

Tags: c#, reference, weak-references

I am studying about `System.WeakReference` in C# and have found a strange behavior in it. Have a look at the code below:

```
public class MainClass
{
    public class Fruit
    {
        public Fruit(string name) { this.Name = name; }

        public string Name { get; private set; }
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        Fruit orange = new Fruit("Orange");
        Fruit orangeStrong = orange;
        WeakReference orangeWeak = new WeakReference(orange);

        orange = null;
        orangeStrong = null;

        GC.Collect(0, GCCollectionMode.Forced);
        GC.WaitForFullGCComplete();

        Fruit orangeNew = ((Fruit)orangeWeak.Target);
        Console.WriteLine(orangeNew.Name);
    }
}
```

This code, as expected, throws an `NullReferenceException` since `orange` is garbage collected. However, adding a line at the bottom as:

```
public class MainClass
{
    public class Fruit
    {
        public Fruit(string name) { this.Name = name; }

        public string Name { get; private set; }
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        Fruit orange = new Fruit("Orange");
        Fruit orangeStrong = orange;
        WeakReference orangeWeak = new WeakReference(orange);

        orange = null;
        orangeStrong = null;

        GC.Collect(0, GCCollectionMode.Forced);
        GC.WaitForFullGCComplete();

        Fruit orangeNew = ((Fruit)orangeWeak.Target);
        Console.WriteLine(orangeNew.Name);
        Console.WriteLine(orangeNew == null ? "" : orangeNew.Name);
    }
}
```

makes `orange` no longer garbage collected and the code runs without an exception.

Is there any reasons for this strange behavior?

Comment: Just to check - you're running these from release builds rather than debug, correct? (Debug builds can extend object lifetimes)

Comment: The first version also prints "Orange" for me on debug build: https://dotnetfiddle.net/Dlf1Rw

Comment: When I compile the code you posted as a release build and run the program from a command line prompt, both versions crash with `NullReferenceException` just as one would expect. Note that **regardless of build configuration or calls to `GC.Collect()`**, the .NET GC system is non-deterministic in the sense that objects may remain technically reachable even if you think you have made them unreachable. Questions asking why something did or did not get GC'ed are not that useful, and your question in particular doesn't seem reliably reproducible.